# strip tags placing a delimiter or store to an array using PHP

Tags: php, strip-tags

I've stripped the tag data from an url like

```
$url='http://abcd.com';
$d=stripslashes(file_get_contents($url));
echo strip_tags($d);
```

but unfortunately all the tag values are clubbed together like `user14036100  9.00user23034003  11.33user32028000  14.00` where in the user1, user2, user3 attributes are stored, It is hard to analyse the attribute values as all are joined together by `strip_tags()`.

so friends can someone help me to strip each tag and store in an array or by placing a delimiter at the end of each stripped tag data.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you able to provide a copy of the original data that you are retrieving from the url? That will help to determine how the data should be processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this with `strip_tags()`, since it justs removes the tags. You wan't to replace them with e.g. a whitespace character (new line, space, ..).
You should probably do this with a regex call, which just replaces all tags.

**A better way** would be to parse the fetched page with [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), so that you can derive the structure directly from the HTML structure.

### Example of usage of DOMDocument

You have the following example html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is my title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="someDataHere">
            <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Population</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Germany</td>
                <td>81,779,600</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Belgium</td>
                <td>11,007,020</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Netherlands</td>
                <td>16,847,007</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can use `DOMDocument` to fetch the entries in the table:

```
$url = "...";
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));

$preparedData = array();
$table = $dom->getElementById("someDataHere");
$tableRows = $table->getElementsByTagName('tr');

foreach ($tableRows as $tableRow)
{
    $columns = $tableRow->getElementsByTagName('td');

    // skip the header row of the table - it has no <td>, just <th>
    if (0 == $columns->length)
    {
        continue;
    }

    $preparedData[ $columns->item(0)->nodeValue ] = $columns->item(1)->nodeValue;
}
```

`$preparedData` will now hold the following data:

```
Array
(
    [Germany] => 81,779,600
    [Belgium] => 11,007,020
    [Netherlands] => 16,847,007
)
```

#### Some notes

- Since you are developing a crawler (spider), you are highly dependent on the HTML structure of the target webpage. You may have to adjust your crawler every time they change something in their templates.
- This is just a simple example, but it should make clear, how you can now use it, to produce more advanced results.
- Since `DOMDocument` implements the DOM methods, you have to work your way through the HTML structure with the possibilities they provide.
- For very huge HTML pages `DOMDocument` can become quite expensive in terms of memory.

Comment: thanks for the thought provoking information. I would be more happy if you can please quote with an example as i'm a newbie to programming. ;)

Comment: I adjusted my answer to include a small example script.